# % in URL redirecting to HTTP ERROR 400 intead of default error page

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have used java servlets in Backend and Angular UI
In my web.xml I have added below code to redirect any invalid URL's

```
<error-page>
    <location>/assets/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

This is working fine except for %.
When I enter % after my URL it gives  HTTP ERROR 400
[image]

How can I redirect even this to /assets/error.html ?

Below is the behavior when I add "&" and it is expected behavior as it redirects to my error page:
[image]

Please help.

Comment: My guess is that it's because the percent character is trying to be interpreted further up the chain - it never even gets to your webapp because it's totally invalid.  But I'm curious - why does it matter?  It's purely a display issue at this point as the correct HTTP status - 400 - is returned.

Comment: Hello Stdunbar.
My requirement is that i show a custom error page . Thats why i wanted to track it.Will I have to change some config file in tomcat?

Comment: Like yes stack overflow shows default error page 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438402/in-url-redirecting-to-http-error-400-intead-of-default-error-page/%
But google shows a custom error page: https://www.google.com/%

Answer (score -1):

try adding this

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/assets/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```